# How to aggregate multiple Query Root Types over micro-services in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, graphql, microservices

I have a `Ruby+GraphQL` project built out of micro-services and a front end that uses `ember-apollo`. I am still learning all of these technologies and am pretty new to the concept of micro-services.

I have three modules in my API - `Clients`, `Collaborators` and `main` (which can be seen as the umbrella of the others), each, excepting `main`, with their own `graphql` directory that contains their respective `QueryType`, along with the types/resolvers, and a `schema` that is located outside these modules.

Since the `schema` can have **only one** `query` type, what I thought of is to somehow aggregate the fields in my other `QueryTypes` in a manner like [this one](https://m.alphasights.com/graphql-ruby-clean-up-your-query-type-d7ab05a47084) with a `FieldCombiner` in the `main` module, sort of as an entry-point, and use that one in my schema.

The problem with this solution is that it uses the old `.define` style which is going to be removed in `graphql 2.0`, so I believe a [class-based-api](https://graphql-ruby.org/schema/class_based_api.html) is a better solution. I searched quite a bit and did not come across something that works in that direction.

What I'd like to do in code:

```
module OpenCompanyApi
  class Schema < GraphQL::Schema
    query Clients::Graphql::Types::Query
    query Collaborators::Graphql::Types::Query # Something like that. They're two different modules, each with their own root query type
    mutation Clients::Graphql::Types::Mutation
    mutation Collaborators::Graphql::Types::Mutation # This too
  end
end
```

Comment: Deprecated by who? In favour of what?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin in favor of the [class-based API](https://graphql-ruby.org/schema/class_based_api.html). It uses the `.define` style, which is going to be removed in `graphql 2.0`.

Comment: Can you share a repo with your code?

Comment: @hernanvicente unfortunately not, as the repo is private. I added some code to better explain what I'd like to do. Since a schema can only have **one** query/mutation type, I thought of somehow stitching all those queries together and the mutations together and just import those two in my `schema.rb`.